# i want to take only simple url without http://

Tags: objective-c

i want to add "http://" inside code so that user find it easy to browse by only typing a simple url

i have tried

```
- (IBAction)uurl:(id)sender {
    NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString : @"http://"];
}
```

but its not working

Comment: no ,no error coming ... still i have to type http://

Comment: `NSLog myurl` what it prints?

Comment: Where do you use the "simple url" the user has typed in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is what the user types, depending on the type of input you use
NSString *urlString = @"www.bla.com"; 

NSString *httpString = @"http://";
urlString = [httpString stringByAppendingString:urlString];

//OR urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",urlString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Right this is simple enough to do but we need to check as well if the user inputs the `http://` or `https://` themselves. So see below with explanation in comments

```
- (IBAction)uurl:(id)sender 
{
    // Our to NSStrings that we want to be checking for.
    static NSString *httpsStr = @"https://";
    static NSString *httpStr = @"http://";

    NSString *urlStr = @"www.google.com"; // User input however you take this

    // Our check to make sure that the urlStr passed in does already have http or https
    if(![urlStr hasPrefix:httpsStr] && ![urlStr hasPrefix:httpStr]) {
        // If it doesn't have anything our default HTTP Protocol will be http
        urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", urlStr];
    }

    // If the user has entered the http or https themselves ignore reseting to http
    // Set our urlStr as the URL we want to use.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    // At this point you would do whatever it is you want to do with the url
}
```

Comment: it says "expected identifier or ( " what should i do ?

Comment: Check your code this has been tested and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-initWithScheme:host:path:`

```
// your user input string
NSString *userString = @"www.apple.com";

NSURL *yourURL;

if (![userString hasPrefix:@"http://"])
     yourURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http" host:userString path:@"/"];
else
     yourURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:userString];
```

Comment: I'm all up for using `initWithScheme:host:path:` but how does your code handle a situation when I pass in `http://www.apple.com`?

Comment: @Popeye You answered to this question on your own answer, use `hasPrefix:` to check if scheme is already present in user string. My code is just about how to correctly use of `-initWithScheme:host:path:`

Comment: I'm not talking about my code ignore my code act like it doesn't exist. I'm trying to help improve your answer, but if you don't want it. I simply don't agree with your answer as it could cause more issues -1 please note I gave the chance to improve before downvote.

Comment: Improved answer so have removed -1

Comment: @Popeye I edit my answer, but you can still downvote it, has it don't check if user string is a valid host.

Comment: I was skeptical about whether or not to include validating the host myself but it doesn't ask about validating the host itself and your code will not come out with any issues based on what has been asked now so I am happy to have removed my -1.